# 9patch image not recognized

Tags: android, android-image, nine-patch

I have created some images for the android app. I have gone through all the steps necessary to create the 9patch image, but to no avail. The application won't just recognise the file.

What I have tried so far:

- Created the image in various PNG bit modes
- Left 1px border and even 2px border at the edges
- Ran it through the draw9patch tool to produce the result posted below
- Ensured the application reads other 9patches
- Tried a random 9patch image that should be working and put it in xxhdpi folder, but it still displays as is, with black lines

I am using **xxhdpi** images.

Here's the code I'm using to detect the 9patch and display it:

```
...
Bitmap bitmap = Resources.getBitmap(context, identifier);
byte[] chunk = bitmap.getNinePatchChunk();
            if (NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(chunk)) {
                drawable = new NinePatchDrawable(bitmap, chunk, new Rect(), null);
            } else {
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
...
```

Here's my 9patch image:

[image: button.9.png]

And here's the result

[image: result]

I have run out of ideas on what to try next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is your xml code in which you are applying .9png ?

Comment: I edited the first post and included the code as well. I'm not using XML (it's an already written code by someone else that I'm just updating pictures for).

Comment: try setting `padding="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Just design only indicator and make use it , don't make whole background..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/expander_open_holo_light" android:state_empty="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/expander_close_holo_light" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/expander_open_holo_light"></item>

</selector>
```

apple like android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicatornew"

Comment: Well this is a workaround and I'm not really the app developer, so I would prefer only creating the right images. It worked with mdpi/hdpi with old image versions, but none of my created files are getting recognized.